# Resource Not Found Azure Cosmos DB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Hi We are facing issue while querying . The document exists in the database.

> "Message: {\"Errors\":[\"Resource Not Found\"]}\r\nActivityId:
>   03866338-6596-49b6-8704-1726cb373bfb, Request URI:
>   /apps/ab277caf-ee90-4cc3-96cb-4d4ec5ae2b13/services/17e48284-a3a0-40c5-b5ec-40bd3f207472/partitions/27cb7777-5add-4f72-8a73-1fc8fe34e7bf/replicas/131603393672093060p/,
>   RequestStats: , SDK: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Common/1.19.162.2"

Document in Database

```
{
    "consumername": "testconsumer",
    "tablename": "Table1",
    "securityaccount": "v-naagga",
    "logtime": "2018-01-13T21:42:21.3040338-08:00",
    "securitydefinition": {
        "tablename": "table1",
        "ColumnList": {
            "columnname": "name",
            "columndatatype": "string"
        },
        "RowSecurity": {
            "columnname": "address",
            "operator": "operator",
            "condition": "somecondition"
        }
    },
    "id": "15554839-096d-4072-8f38-af2e9c64b452",
    "_rid": "LmUiAONSDQQBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/LmUiAA==/colls/LmUiAONSDQQ=/docs/LmUiAONSDQQBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00002e04-0000-0000-0000-5a5aedd60000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1515908566
}
```

Below is the update method code which is throwing this Error

```
{
            try
            {
                RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
                options.PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(id);
                options.ConsistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.Session;
                return await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, SecurityCollectionId, id), item,options).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Log(ErrorLevel.Error, ex.Message);
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi, any updates now? Does my answer helps you?

Comment: Hi Jay Thanks for checking i checked in my code i m passing correct values for parition. So issue still exists ...

Comment: Hi,Naveen. Please see my update answer. The code works well for me. If any concern, please let me know.

Answer (score 7):

According to my observations, I think your issue should be partition key settings error.

Please refer to this [official document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtJLA.png).You need to provide the value of the partition key, not the name of the field which stores the partition key.

For example , my container is created like this:

[image]

The partition key is "name" for my collection here. You could check your collection's partition key.

And my documents as below :

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "jay"
}

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "jay2"
}
```

My `partitionkey` is **'name'**, so here I have two paritions : **'jay'** and **'jay1'**.

So, here you should set the `partitionkey` property to 'jay' or 'jay2',not 'name'.

```
try
   {
     RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
     options.PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("jay");
     options.ConsistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.Session;
     return await client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(DatabaseId, SecurityCollectionId, id), item,options).ConfigureAwait(false);
   }
     catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Logger.Log(ErrorLevel.Error, ex.Message);
     throw ex;
   }
```

Hope it helps you.

---

***Update Answer :***

I created a sample document as same as yours and replaced it successfully. 
[image]

Please refer to my test code.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Program
    {

        private static DocumentClient client;

        static string endpoint = "***";
        static string key = "***";
        static string database = "***";
        static string collection = "***";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpoint), key);

            try
            {
                Sample querysample = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Sample>(
                UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(database, collection))
                .Where(so => so.id == "1")
                .AsEnumerable()
                .First();

                Console.WriteLine(querysample.tablename);

                querysample.tablename = "Table2";

                RequestOptions options = new RequestOptions();
                options.PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("1");
                options.ConsistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.Session;
                var result =  client.ReplaceDocumentAsync(UriFactory.CreateDocumentUri(database, collection, "1"), querysample, options).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }


            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public class Sample
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string tablename { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`id` is my partition key and the value is `'1'`. Would you please check the differences between our codes?

If any concern , please let me know.

Comment: @Hardrada Really appreciate to your affirmation.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was something basic, I had the container name spelt incorrectly.  If you are getting a 404 worth checking you are indeed calling the right database and container